# Github CI run getting failed without change from 15 June ERROR: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/folders/sp/m

Tags: ios, github-actions, devops, github-actions-runners, github-ci

*CI job was working fine and it was posting the build successfully but after 15th June (Tentative) it started getting failed and unable to identify the reason why. Getting below error. Can somebody please help or provide direction using that I can fix it?*

**Log when getting an error:**

```
2023-06-23T10:04:28.4433590Z ** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
2023-06-23T10:04:28.4435780Z 
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5632280Z (node:7479) [DEP0147] DeprecationWarning: In future versions of Node.js, fs.rmdir(path, { recursive: true }) will be removed. Use fs.rm(path, { recursive: true }) instead
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5633660Z (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5697570Z node:fs:1551
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5701290Z   handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5703110Z   ^
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5703440Z 
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5704880Z Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/folders/sp/m5rks75d44j30f37y5h1j3tr0000gn/T/AppName.xcarchive'
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5705820Z     at Object.statSync (node:fs:1551:3)
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5706560Z     at __node_internal_ (node:internal/fs/utils:799:8)
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5707300Z     at Object.rmdirSync (node:fs:1169:15)
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5708650Z     at ArchiveBuildAction.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/work/ios/ios/.github/actions/xcode-build/dist/index.js:14571:28)
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5710410Z     at step (/Users/runner/work/ios/ios/.github/actions/xcode-build/dist/index.js:14453:23)
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5712240Z     at Object.next (/Users/runner/work/ios/ios/.github/actions/xcode-build/dist/index.js:14434:53)
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5713310Z     at /Users/runner/work/ios/ios/.github/actions/xcode-build/dist/index.js:14428:71
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5714100Z     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5715110Z     at module.exports.__webpack_modules__.7919.__awaiter (/Users/runner/work/ios/ios/.github/actions/xcode-build/dist/index.js:14424:12)
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5716500Z     at ArchiveBuildAction.module.exports.__webpack_modules__.7919.ArchiveBuildAction.finish (/Users/runner/work/ios/ios/.github/actions/xcode-build/dist/index.js:14560:20) {
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5717820Z   errno: -2,
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5718440Z   syscall: 'stat',
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5719050Z   code: 'ENOENT',
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5719860Z   path: '/var/folders/sp/m5rks75d44j30f37y5h1j3tr0000gn/T/AppName.xcarchive'
2023-06-23T10:04:28.5720610Z }
```

**CI.yml: Specific Archive code**

```
archive:
    name: Archive
    runs-on: macos-13
    needs: prepare
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{ fromJson(needs.prepare.outputs.archive-matrix) }}
    steps:
      - name: Install SSH key
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.4.1
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.ORG_SSHKEY }}
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.ORG_GHTOKEN }}
          submodules: recursive
      - name: Install pods
        uses: ./.github/actions/install-pods
      - name: Apply changes
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: ${{ env.ARTIFACT_CHANGES }}
          path: ./
      - name: Setup code signing
        id: setup-code-signing
        uses: ./.github/actions/setup-code-signing
        with:
          verbose: true
          private-key: ${{ secrets.CODE_SIGNING_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          provisioning-profile: ${{ matrix.provisioning-profile }}
      - name: Create archive
        id: create-archive
        uses: ./.github/actions/xcode-build
        with:
          actions: archive
          workspace: ${{ env.XC_WORKSPACE }}
          scheme: ${{ env.XC_SCHEME }}
          sdk: iphoneos
          settings: |
            CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED: false
            DEVELOPMENT_TEAM: ${{ fromJSON(steps.setup-code-signing.outputs.development-team)[0] }}
            PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_${{ env.XC_SCHEME }}: ${{ steps.setup-code-signing.outputs.bundle-identifier }}
      - name: Update entitlements
        run: |
          PRODUCT_NAME=$(xcodebuild -scheme ${{ env.XC_SCHEME }} -showBuildSettings | sed -n "s/^[[:space:]]*PRODUCT_NAME = \(.*\)/\1/p")
          ENTITLEMENTS=$PRODUCT_NAME.entitlements
          EXECUTABLE=${{ steps.create-archive.outputs.archive-path }}/Products/Applications/$PRODUCT_NAME.app
          echo '${{ steps.setup-code-signing.outputs.entitlements }}' | plutil -convert xml1 -o $ENTITLEMENTS -- -
          codesign --entitlements $ENTITLEMENTS -f -s '${{ fromJSON(steps.setup-code-signing.outputs.code-sign-identities)[0] }}' $EXECUTABLE
      - name: Export archive
        id: export-archive
        uses: ./.github/actions/xcode-build
        with:
          exportArchive: true
          archivePath: ${{ steps.create-archive.outputs.archive-path }}
          exportPath: ./
          exportOptions: |
            compileBitcode: false
            method: ${{ matrix.export-method }}
            signingStyle: manual
            teamID: ${{ fromJSON(steps.setup-code-signing.outputs.development-team)[0] }}
            provisioningProfiles:
               ${{ steps.setup-code-signing.outputs.bundle-identifier }}: ${{ matrix.provisioning-profile }}
      - name: Upload product
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: ${{ steps.export-archive.outputs.product-name }} (${{ matrix.export-method }})
          path: ${{ steps.export-archive.outputs.product-path }}
      - name: Upload symbols
        run: |
          for file in ./Analytics/GoogleService-Info*.plist; do
            bundle_id=$(plutil -extract BUNDLE_ID xml1 -o - $file | sed -n "s/.*<string>\(.*\)<\/string>.*/\1/p")
            if [[ $bundle_id == ${{ steps.setup-code-signing.outputs.bundle-identifier }} ]]; then
              ./Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp $file -p ios ${{ steps.create-archive.outputs.archive-path }}/dSYMs
            fi
          done

  prepare-to-publish:
    name: Prepare to Publish
    runs-on: macos-13
```

[image: This is the .gitHub folder structure where actions and code sign are submodules]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**So Finally I got to know about below link:**

https://github.blog/changelog/2023-06-13-github-actions-all-actions-will-run-on-node16-instead-of-node12-by-default/

**GitHub Actions: All Actions will run on Node16 instead of Node12 by default**

Node12 has been out of support since April 2022. As a result we have started the deprecation process of Node12 for GitHub Actions. We plan to migrate all actions to run on Node16 by Summer 2023.
Following on from our warning in workflows using Node12 we will start enforcing the use of Node16 rather than Node12 on the 14th of June.

To opt out of this and continue using Node12 while it is still available in the runner, you can choose to set `ACTIONS_ALLOW_USE_UNSECURE_NODE_VERSION=true`
as an 'env' in their workflow or as an environment variable on your runner machine. This will only work until we upgrade the runner removing Node12 later in the summer.

With this temporary change `ACTIONS_ALLOW_USE_UNSECURE_NODE_VERSION=true` in CI.yml, I am successfully able to post the build.